# to grep specific set of strings occuring multiple times in a single line

Tags: linux, shell

MY system generate very lengthy lines in logs of which i want to grep only few fields values. I tried with grep and sed and I'm nowhere close.

Here, Single log line contains multiple Channel fields and its analysis. 
How to get a specific Channel (occurring more than once) from a single log line which contains many such channel information.
For e.g. here i need video channel analysis and it's occurring twice in line.

> .......{"Channel":{"Type": "Video","Protocol": "DYNAMIC_96","Rate":
>   "1999102","Packets":{"Forwarded":{"Total": "570495","RTPAndRTCP":
>   "570495","KeepAlives": "0","Unknown": "0"},"KeepAlives":{"Total":
>   "0","Assent": "0","H460": "0","STUN": "0"},"Errors":{"Total":
>   "0","Media":{"NoDestination": "0","InvalidType": "0","FilterFailure":
>   "0","MediaDiscarded":
>   "0","Filter":{"SRTP":{"Decrypt":{"Authentication": "0","Decrypt":
>   "0","BadRTPHeader": "0","FECIgnored": "0","Other":
>   "0"}},"RTP":{"Payload":{"Rewrite":{"Unexpected":
>   "0"}}}}},"Assent":{"InvalidProbe": "0"},"IP":{"Send":
>   "0"}},"Analysis":{"Duplicate": "0","Lost": "4","OutOfOrder":
>   "1","Unexpected": "0","Jitter": "8","JitterPeak":
>   "48"}},"Incoming":{"Leg": "BSide"},"Outgoing":{"Leg":
>   "ASide"}}},.....................{"Channel":{"Type":
>   "Video","Protocol": "DYNAMIC_96","Rate":
>   "1617864","Packets":{"Forwarded":{"Total": "407214","RTPAndRTCP":
>   "407214","KeepAlives": "0","Unknown": "0"},"KeepAlives":{"Total":
>   "0","Assent": "0","H460": "0","STUN": "0"},"Errors":{"Total":
>   "0","Media":{"NoDestination": "0","InvalidType": "0","FilterFailure":
>   "0","MediaDiscarded": "0","Filter":{"SRTP":{"Encrypt":{"Encrypt":
>   "0","BadRTPHeader": "0","FECIgnored": "0","DatagramSizeExceeded":
>   "0","Other": "0"}},"RTP":{"Payload":{"Rewrite":{"Unexpected":
>   "0"}}}}},"Assent":{"InvalidProbe": "0"},"IP":{"Send":
>   "0"}},"Analysis":{"Duplicate": "0","Lost": "1045","OutOfOrder":
>   "0","Unexpected": "957","Jitter": "3","JitterPeak":
>   "1143"}},"Incoming":{"Leg": "ASide"},"Outgoing":{"Leg":
>   "BSide"}}},......

I am interested only in above these 2 channel analysis and to throw all blah blah (.....) information.

Any pointers will be of great help. Thanks !!

Comment: please [edit] and show what is the exact expected output.

Comment: The line feeds in the above input file have been reformatted.  To paste text from some code use the *"{}"* (Code Sample) button, not the *'"'* (Blockquote) button.  _Blockquote_ reformats text by default, _Code Sample_ does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the channels from the line you can use:

```
grep -Eo '"Channel":{[^{]+({[^}]+})+}'
```

This will output for your example:

```
"Channel":{"Type": "Video","Protocol": "DYNAMIC_96","Rate": "1999102","Packets":{"Forwarded":{"Total": "570495","RTPAndRTCP": "570495","KeepAlives": "0","Unknown": "0"},"KeepAlives":{"Total": "0","Assent": "0","H460": "0","STUN": "0"},"Errors":{"Total": "0","Media":{"NoDestination": "0","InvalidType": "0","FilterFailure": "0","MediaDiscarded": "0","Filter":{"SRTP":{"Decrypt":{"Authentication": "0","Decrypt": "0","BadRTPHeader": "0","FECIgnored": "0","Other": "0"}}
"Channel":{"Type": "Video","Protocol": "DYNAMIC_96","Rate": "1617864","Packets":{"Forwarded":{"Total": "407214","RTPAndRTCP": "407214","KeepAlives": "0","Unknown": "0"},"KeepAlives":{"Total": "0","Assent": "0","H460": "0","STUN": "0"},"Errors":{"Total": "0","Media":{"NoDestination": "0","InvalidType": "0","FilterFailure": "0","MediaDiscarded": "0","Filter":{"SRTP":{"Encrypt":{"Encrypt": "0","BadRTPHeader": "0","FECIgnored": "0","DatagramSizeExceeded": "0","Other": "0"}}
```